# How to include identical if block in multiple functions?

Tags: python

I'm sorry to ask such a basic question, but what's the Pythonic way to include the same if block that can conditionally return in multiple functions? Here's my setup:

```
def a():
  if bool:
    return 'yeehaw'
  return 'a'

def b():
  if bool:
    return 'yeehaw'
  return 'b'
```

I'd like to factor the common conditional out of the two functions, but I'm not sure how to do so.

Comment: Is `bool` a local or global variable in your code? Note that `bool` is a built-in Python function so it is not a good idea to use it a variable name.

Comment: yup, call it `bool_` trailing _'s standard Python-custom for avoiding clashes with builtins.

Comment: @JLPeyret Calling a variable `bool` or `bool_` does not say what the True/False value means so it is a bad variable name and will not pass any review

Comment: This is all pseudo code, and `bool` was just meant to indicate the variable type. `bool` is defined within each function (ie is local).

Answer (score 5):

Use a decorator or closure

```
def my_yeehaw(result):
  def yeehaw():
    if some_bool:
      return 'yeehaw'
    return result
  return yeehaw

a = my_yeehaw('a')
b = my_yeehaw('b')
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use a decorator but this sent me on the right path :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a lambda that takes in a. `bool` and a default value to return if the condition is false:

```
check = lambda condition, default: 'yeehaw' if condition else default
```

```
def a():
     return check(condition, 'a')

def b():
     return check(condition, 'b')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new to python but I think you can use a default argument to send a or b based on what is passed to the function.

```
def a(x='a'):
    if condition: #where condition can be True or False
        return 'yeehaw'
    return x
```

Comment: but how do you implement `b()`? `b = lambda : a('b')`

Comment: sorry. If you call function a with value b, it will print b. For example, print (a('b')) will print b.  It will print only when the if statement is false.

Comment: however, i do get what you are saying. There are two functions: a and b. The question is to find a common way to print the if statement.  Your response makes sense now.

Comment: I just changed the True to a condition statement. The original question had bool which is a True or False. I should have been a bit more explicit.  Anyway, this answer may not fully solve the problem.    I am new here. How does it work. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: naw, it's fine now.  No worries about being new, we've been there at some point, though some fine folk seem to forget that and swing the downvotes willy-nilly.  welcome aboard.

Answer (score 1):

(note:  my naming wasn't the best, consider that `same_bool` function might be better called `identical_if_block(...)` to follow your example
And I am also assuming bool_ is a parameter, though it could work as a global.  But not as `bool` which, like any function object, is always Truthy

```
>>> bool(bool)
True
```

)

Use a function, as long as it doesn't need to return falsies.

```
def same_bool(bool_):
    " works for any result except a Falsy"
    return "yeehaw" if bool_ else None

def a(bool_):
    res = same_bool(bool_)
    if res:
        return res
    return 'a'

def b(bool_, same_bool_func):
    #you can pass in your boolean chunk function
    res = same_bool_func(bool_)
    if res:
        return res
    return 'b'


print ("a(True):", a(True))
print ("a(False):", a(False))
print ("b(True, same_bool):", b(True,same_bool))
print ("b(False, same_bool):", b(False,same_bool))
```

output:

```
a(True): yeehaw
a(False): a
b(True, same_bool): yeehaw
b(False, same_bool): b
```

If you do need falsies, use a special guard value

```
   def same_bool(bool_):
        " works for any result"
        return False if bool_ else NotImplemented

   def a(bool_):
        res = same_bool(bool_)
        if res is not NotImplemented:
            return res
        return 'a'
```

You could also feed in `"a"` and `"b"` since they are constant results, but I assume that's only in your simplified example.

```
   def same_bool(bool_, val):
        return "yeehaw" if bool_ else val

   def a(bool_):
        return same_bool(bool_, "a")
```

Comment: And now you have the same type of code duplication that the OP wants to get rid of

Comment: @rioV8 true enough, *if one assumes that this minimal code example is all there is*.  I assumed that the if block is *significantly bigger* and that it gets repeated more than twice.  Otherwise, this wouldn't  be worth it at all.  Likewise, while I did not think much of `bool` as a variable name, I stated the typical Python solution of appending underscore to predefined common names, `cls_`, `self_`, `filter_` etc as I lacked context to what the OP's domain is.  All in all, when one has nothing kind, or clever, to say, might be best to say nothing at all, eh?

Comment: `cls`, `self` do not need an `_` and have a specific meaning, although the name is arbitrary, but the name tells something about what it refers to. `bool_` only tells something about what the possible type of the variable is.

Comment: @rioV8 you just love arguing, dontcha?  consider this - if the OP had made clear that his intent was to enable functions with simple constants `a`,`b`, `7` then I would never have proposed this solution - a curry would do the trick.  and, more importantly, if it wasn't just a, b, 7, your solution does nada, i.e. is a very specific simplest case scenario.  have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up liking the decorator syntax, as the functions that include the duplicative conditional logic have a good deal else going on in them:

```
# `function` is the decorated function
# `args` & `kwargs` are the inputs to `function`
def yeehaw(function):
  def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    if args[0] == 7: return 99 # boolean check
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  return decorated
    
@yeehaw
def shark(x):
  return str(x)

shark(7)
```

Comment: Reference: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-FYfgqjECs1I/TeJoA2899DI/AAAAAAAAEII/7js84oWpRPk/s400/tumblr_kuxr34jtOb1qzeu38o1_400.png